# Format date in Values for a Range (Gant) Chart SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a date column in which the dates are re-curring every year.  I'm only interested in the month really, but I can't just put the month number as the high and low value for the gant chart.  Is there any way I can format the column? Any suggestions would be awesome.

The gant chart currently is taking the whole date and is working fine, but like I said it goes out to the next year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. So the DATECOLUMN I had was formated as such:

**Example: 2013-01-01 00:00:0.000**

In order to put in the **GANT(RANGE) CHART** in the series property, under values, I formated the Top Value and Low Value as **=MONTH(DATECOLUMN)** using the **expression option.**

Then for the **Horizontal Axis Properties** I set the **Interval to 1** and **Interval Type** to **Number**.  And There you have it Monthly time spans with only the Months 1 - 12 showing.

I must also note that I only had one time recorded.  So I just did Top Value as: **DATEADD(MM,1,DATECOLUMN)** In Order to get the right time span in my dataset Script.

Answer (score 0):

Which date format would u like to display in your chart.

## If (month with year) like 'Sep 2013'

use this date  format for the same.

```
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),getutcdate(), 113),4,8)
```

Comment: I probably should've specified formating of the date. Thanks Though!